# State update only affects component if it affects parents' style

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I have an app that lets the user scan for and connect to BLE devices. If the user taps a scan result, I want a spinner to show next to the device while the connection is in progress.

I am using Redux to keep track of discovered and connected devices. The main App component is connect with redux-react and passes the relevant bits of state to its children.

One of these children is the list of scan results, which in turn passes one device to each of its entries. The scan list items look like this:

```
class DeviceListItem extends Component{
render = () => {
    return <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress}>
        <Card>
            <View style={{justifyContent: "space-between", flexDirection: "row", flex:1, width:"100%", alignItems: this.props.item.pendingActions !== 0?"flex-start":undefined}>
                <Text>{this.props.item.name}</Text>
                <ActivityIndicator animating= {this.props.item.pendingActions !== 0}  color={Colors.accent} size="small"/>
            </View>
        </Card>
    </TouchableOpacity>
}
}
```

Now, in the style of the View component you might notice this peculiar snippet of code:

```
 alignItems: this.props.item.pendingActions !== 0?"flex-start":undefined
```

For some reason, this is required to make the spinner show up when the state of the device changes. It seems that in order to make the spinner show up on a state update is to make the style of the parent view depend on the state. It doesn't seem to matter which property changes, but it needs to change in some way in order for the spinner to be affected by the update.

Does anyone have an idea about what's going on here? I'm still fairly new to Redux and React Native so there's a chance I am misusing something here but this just seems odd to me.

Answer (score 0):

When updating `props` the component isn't self-aware about props changes.
When you update the parent state, and the props has been changed, it will trigger a render at the parent, that will also re-render the child you are talking about.

When updating a prop value, without triggering a render, the child will not re-render.

To make it aware about props changes you have to use `componentDidUpdate`.

An example would be:

```
componentDidUpdate=(prevProps)=>{
   if (prevProps!==this.props)
       this.setState({propsChanged:!this.state.propsChanged})
}
```

To use the example above, you have to define a state variable called `propsChanged`.

Hope this helps you understand the problem and find a solution that suits you!